# Smart Contract Address for ChainLink FeedRegistry on the Binance Smart Chain

Tags: binance, chainlink

I am looking for the address of the Chainlink FeedRegistry on the Binance Smart Chain similar to the one deployed for Ethereum https://etherscan.io/address/0x47Fb2585D2C56Fe188D0E6ec628a38b74fCeeeDf#code

Answer (score 0):

The Chainlink FeedRegistry is only available for ETH Mainnet and Kovan right now.

You can find the address for all networks in [reference-contracts](https://docs.chain.link/docs/reference-contracts/)